# Bitbucket doesnt see new added files

Tags: git, bitbucket

After some branch merges bitbucket doesnt see new added files.

Its okay on local master branch. When i do push its up to date.
On commits pages files appears but not in source files

Comment: please try git cache and push again

Answer (score 0):

It usually means that your local branch does not have a upstream branch to push to. This happens when a branch is locally created. On versions of git < 2.x.x, git will show a message- Everything up-to-date. What it actually means is there is no remote set up with this branch, so according to a remote view, everything is up to date. 
In order to see your files on remote, you need to use the following-

```
git push -u origin <local-branch-name>
```

This will create a branch on remote and your local is now set to track your newly created remote branch.

On git versions > 2.x.x, git shows a completely different message while pushing a newly created local branch to remote for the first time-

```
$> git push 
fatal: The current branch my-branch has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin my-branch
```

This message is not as misleading as the first one. So, you can either update your git version or push the way as stated earlier. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for responce. That did not help. I have > 2.x.x version and tried second one solution.
Probably i have to say, that on bitbucket links like:
https://bitbucket.org/username/repo/commits/hash/ i can see the changes.
but when i move to https://bitbucket.org/username/repo i dont see this files and get an error